Are there any quotas on Firebase auth reload() method?
I have a flutter app in which I want to logout a user from app when someone disables that account from firebase console. I have referred to this: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10968
. Calling FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload() is working but I'm not sure if there are any quotas or restrictions on how frequently this method can be called. I've referred to the doc but it doesn't mention anything specific to this.
I have implemented the functionality & it is working as expected. I'm just not sure if there are restrictions imposed on this or if this a good practice.

The reload() will refresh the user from the server. There is no quotas or limit on this function call. Usually you use it if you have sent a verification email to the user then you would check the property emailVerified of the User object which will return true or false accordingly.
In terms of limitation regarding Firebase Authentication you can check here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Yes, but from this reference https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10968 . This method could also be used to check if a user account is disabled or deleted from firebase auth. Basically I want to use it to logout a user from app when his account is disabled from firebase auth console. So I was thinking of verifying the account status using reload() before calls to firebase APIs from app.
